# Django mailbox refresh button in template

Tags: python, django, email

I'm using django-mailbox in my app.
It works but it syncs mail by "python manage.py getmail" in shell.

Now my goal is to refresh new incoming mail by html template.

Is there any such way?

TY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run management commands from your code

Pls see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code

so basically

```
from django.core import management

management.call_command('getmail')
```

If you add create a custom view and call

```
management.call_command('getmail')
```

You should have your desired behavior